# Migrating azure functions to .net8 isolated, function hangs when triggered

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-8.0

I am migrating from Azure Functions .Net 6 app to .Net 8 isolated and I am testing a demo function called HttpTriggerCSharp by debugging it in Rider (MacOs). The breakpoints have a green tick and when I call the function the browser starts loading but the request does not return and it hangs in loading state. However I can see the request start in the console within Rider:

```
Functions:

        HttpTriggerCSharp: [GET] http://localhost:7071/HttpTriggerCSharp

[2023-11-24T15:00:28.610Z] Executing HTTP request: {
[2023-11-24T15:00:28.610Z]   requestId: "f4e1b834-9dc6-4ecc-9b19-91ee4b3d881f",
[2023-11-24T15:00:28.610Z]   method: "GET",
[2023-11-24T15:00:28.610Z]   userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
[2023-11-24T15:00:28.610Z]   uri: "/HttpTriggerCSharp"
[2023-11-24T15:00:28.610Z] }
[2023-11-24T15:00:28.739Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=123456)
[2023-11-24T15:00:28.810Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp' (Succeeded, Id=64dde9e1-69ef-446c-935e-6f6d82a6cb7f, Duration=94ms)
[2023-11-24T15:00:28.832Z] Executed HTTP request: {
[2023-11-24T15:00:28.832Z]   requestId: "123456",
[2023-11-24T15:00:28.832Z]   identities: "(WebJobsAuthLevel:Admin)",
[2023-11-24T15:00:28.832Z]   status: "200",
[2023-11-24T15:00:28.832Z]   duration: "219"
[2023-11-24T15:00:28.832Z] }
[2023-11-24T15:00:31.248Z] Executing HTTP request: {
[2023-11-24T15:00:31.249Z]   requestId: "123456",
[2023-11-24T15:00:31.249Z]   method: "GET",
[2023-11-24T15:00:31.249Z]   userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
[2023-11-24T15:00:31.249Z]   uri: "/HttpTriggerCSharp"
[2023-11-24T15:00:31.249Z] }
[2023-11-24T15:00:31.253Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=123456)
```

Any idea why the call to function hangs and the breakpoint is not hit?

Comment: It's a trivial question but did you changed the stack in the configuration of the Azure Function? 
I've just experienced a long start up time (at least 2') on a Azure Web App after changing the stack from .NET 7 to .NET 8 in the configuration. 
Note that I'm using a Free (F1) plan so the long start up time could depend on this.

Comment: Are you talking about in the cloud? Sorry I didn't mention that I am currently just testing this locally.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about Azure deployment. No problem, I'm sorry but I can't help with debugging in Rider.

Comment: Maybe you have a repository with a minimalist reproduce?

Comment: Check all the Run Profile Settings. That's what's giving me headaches as of lately (just switched from VS to Rider).

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I was calling .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults() on the Hostbuilder during startup. Its configuring some default values including gRPC, maybe that was the problem. Anyway removed this line and it started to work. Thanks for all the suggestions.